# Disabling Chrome autofill is not working with multiple input fields

Tags: html, autofill

In Chrome v.70 (haven't testested in other browsers), if i have the following HTML (https://jsfiddle.net/dgn3yw71/):

```
<form>
  <label for="address">address</label>
  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"/>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
</form>
```

I could also remove "name" input and label and the effect would be as expected: disabling browser autofill for address input.

Now if i add 1 or more input & label like this (https://jsfiddle.net/4tay9weg/):

```
<form>
  <label for="address">address</label>
  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"/>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
  <label for="test">test</label>
  <input type="text" name="test" id="test"/>
</form>
```

Now the address input would not disable browsers autofill as expected

First of all, why? - Secondly, how to fix it?

Comment: This is not possible, because of chrome functionality. The user must disable the "Save and fill addresses" from Chrome settings.

Comment: try this: https://jsfiddle.net/xfpL8am4/ You need an input with autocomplete:off and second inputs use a random string for autocomplete. Works on Chrome 71

Comment: i use <?php echo md5(microtime()) ?>